# Jquery add,remove class in Jquery

Tags: jquery

Sorry for my english (

It is impossible to make a couple of functions.

1. When you click on ".jv-add" add ".cat-hover" and delete ".item" + add html - button that would be pressing it to return everything back. Like all works without Poble.
2. I think over the function return to its former state. That is, when clicked on ".cat-close" (added html) that need to be removed ".car-hover" and html () as well as added ".item"
   Toggle tried, but failed(
3. I have about 13 elements with the class "jv-add" how to do that would at completion, the current function for this entry, all other reset to zero

I will be very grateful for the help!

HTML code:

```
<div class="cat-item">
            <div id="cat" class="jv-add item">
                <h3 class="cat-one head">Name category</h3>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <ul class="onelevel">
                    <li><a href="file.html">Sub category 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html">Sub category 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html">Sub category 3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html">Sub category 4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="file.html">Sub category 5</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Javascript code:

```
$(".cat-item>.jv-add").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("cat-hover").removeClass("item").append('<i class="fa cat-close fa-times"></i>');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could delegate the handling of all events to the container element `cat-item`

```
$(".cat-item")
    .on('click', '.jv-add:not(.cat-hover)', function () {
    $(this)
        .addClass("cat-hover")
        .removeClass("item")
        .append('<i class="fa cat-close fa-times"></i>');
}).on('click', '.cat-close', function (e) {
    $(this)
        .closest('.jv-add')
        .removeClass('cat-hover')
        .addClass('item')
        .find('.cat-close')
        .remove();
    return false;
});
```

**Demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/rUKde/

Comment: this is what you need! super!
Only when you click on the other ".cat-item", others do not return to its initial state.

Comment: @dmitry can you show how is the HTML with multiple `.cat-item`? Are they siblings ?